# Fetch multi-participant conversations with last message for each

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to create a simple chat application database schema, and query the conversations. My current table setup is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE chat_user (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    display_name VARCHAR(140),
    ... other user stuff ...
);

CREATE TABLE conversation (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(140),
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE conversation_message (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    conversation_id bigint NOT NULL,
    sender_id bigint NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE conversation_participant (
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    conversation_id bigint NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

So basically each conversation has its own title, and multiple participants. What I would like to fetch my conversations sorted by the date of the latest message in the conversation (so the conversations with the newest messages are shown first). The result set should contain the id, title of the conversation and list of participants + the id, sender_id and body of the latest message.

It would also be required to fetch the conversations paginated based on the creation date of the conversation (20 per page)

Is my table setup efficient enough to satisfy the above constraint? Seems to me that this could result in a rather large query with multiple subqueries?.

Comment: You can use SQL to achieve what you want. Not sure about performance though. As long as you have few hundred messages and conversations, you might be ok. However, when you have 10's of thousands...

Comment: This is a well designed schema for the purpose you describe.  You may want to update it to show the FK constraints using e.g. `conversation_id bigint not null references conversation(id)`.  Your queries should be simple and perform well so long as your indexing matches your usage.  For instance you would play with indexing `conversation_message.created` and `conversation_message.conversation_id` to work well with a `distinct on` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: What is your question? PS Please do not change your post's question to invalidate reasonable answers, create a new post.

Comment: @philipxy I need a query to achieve the described result set. I only made the requirement more clear (I though it was clear enough in the beginning, Gordon pointed out I need to be more clear)

Comment: Please show sample data expected results so we can be clearer on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the difference between a message sender and a conversation participant? Do not all participants send messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get latest message for your conversations there are ways to achieve it like self joins or window functions (row_number(), rank() etc). Using window function you can write your query as

```
with cm as (
  select *,
  rank() over (partition by conversation_id order by created desc) as r
  from conversation_message
)

select  c.id, 
        c.title, 
        cm.body,
        cm.created,
        cm.r,
        cu.display_name
from conversation as c
left join cm on c.id = cm.conversation_id and cm.r  <= 1
left join chat_user cu on cu.id = cm.sender_id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/id9wnr7GMyihze4XpP7Yxa/3)

In above query I have used  left joins to include conversions with no messages, If you need only conversations which has messages then use inner joins. If you need more than 1 latest messages for each conversation change `cm.r  <= @no`

To get participants list for each conversation you can add new CTE like

```
with cm as (
  select *,
    rank() over (partition by conversation_id order by created desc) as r
  from conversation_message
),
 message_participants as (
  select
    m.conversation_id,
    array_agg(u.display_name order by m.created desc) as participants
  from chat_user as u
  join conversation_message as m on u.id = m.sender_id
  group by m.conversation_id
)

select  c.id, 
        c.title, 
        cm.body,
        cm.created,
        cm.r,
        cu.display_name,
        cmp.participants
from conversation c
left join cm on c.id = cm.conversation_id and cm.r  <= 1
left join chat_user cu on cu.id = cm.sender_id
left join message_participants cmp on c.id = cmp.conversation_id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/id9wnr7GMyihze4XpP7Yxa/5)

Improvements

- Add `user_id` in `conversation` table to identify who has created
  this conversation.
- Table `conversation_participant` is redundant while you can extract
  list of participants from `conversation_message`

Comment: This was really helpful, you did leave out the message_participants table, but I will hopefully figure it out. The table must exist as I need to know the participants of the conversations (even if one of them has not posted a message yet)

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to want a `join` and agregation:

```
select cm.conversation_id, max(created)
from conversation_message cm join
     conversation_participant cp
     on cm.conversation_id = cp.conversation_id
where cp.user_id = ?
group by cm.conversation_id
order by max(created) desc;
```

Comment: Tried this in pgAdmin, I get the conversationId and latest message timestamp for it (works great). But I also need the other data from the conversation table + the data of the latest message (id, body) etc. Since we are agregating here I can not fetch those.

Comment: @Veles . . . Your question explicitly says:  "So I can return each conversation with its corresponding latest message to be shown in UI."  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @George You are right, I reformulated the question to be more clear (when I said the latest message - I meant the whole row)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/queries-table-expressions.html).

So your query would look something like this.
You can fetch all of your needed data, apply limits and offsets, and retrieve the last message for each conversation. Hope it would help.

```
select * from conversation c
left join lateral (
    select * from conversation_message cm 
       where cm.conversation_id=c.id
       order by created desc 
       limit 1
 ) cm on true
 left join conversation_participant cp on cp.id = cm.sender_id;
```

Left joins here are for the chat rooms without any messages.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** I think you have a reasonable design for a `normalized (3NF)` OLTP database. That's what you should aim for, not the number of `JOIN`s for a specific use case. The design you have will satisfy the use case you defined and many other use cases, which I'm sure involved in this application of yours.

**In details:**
You're designing for an OLTP system, where the data is kept normalized to ensure the data consistency and improve the efficiency of OLTP transactions.

This however means you will have to do much more `JOIN`s than a de-normalized database( which is suitable more for OLAP, reporting, analytics systems). This is just the nature of OLTP `relational databases`.

Trying to reduce the number of `JOIN`s in a normalized database (i.e 3NF - [Third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)) means you will be combining data from different granularity into the same table and cause duplication, thus making updates harder and slower, and eventually data inconsistency.

So, you really shouldn't design aiming to reduce the number of `JOIN`s. Instead make sure, you have a normalized design and avoid over-normalizing. In cases, where you may want to avoid writing long queries, you can add `VIEWS` and use view to write queries to simplify your queries (but that can cause sub-optimal query performance sometimes by bringing unnecessary joins).